# How to convert numpy array to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create a numpy array and I want to convert it to am image.

I have this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr3D = np.arange(500*500*3).reshape(500, 500, 3) 
    arr3D[:, :, :] = [255, 0 ,255]                # turn on blue and red, turn off green
    plt.plot(arr3D)
    plt.show()
```

and I get this error:

```
   raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "
ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (500,) and (500, 500, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.imshow()` instead of `plt.plot()`

Comment: That didn't fix it. I ended up with     
plt.imshow(arr3D);
plt.show()

Both lines need to be there, and I'm not sure why that works, but it works.

Comment: yes you need to use `plt.show()` after my solution or else it won't show output.